# Double.parseDouble() returns Infinity when I thought it should be NumberFormatException

Tags: java, android

There is astrange and unexpected behavior of `Double.parseDouble()` method:

```
Double.parseDouble("4cff9d79-a696-4dfc-89f9-a265ae117257");
```

That didn't thrown `NumberFormatException` as expected. The result was `Infinity`. With other UUID's the exception is thrown. Problem is only with Android Java, at Desktop version it works correctly. Why?

**PS:** Used Android API 17, exception repeats on Android 4.4.2 phone.

Comment: Yes. I've read the `Q&A style` rulers page and decided it is approach.

Comment: Please `do` `not` abuse code `formatting`.

Comment: Sorry, I was excided

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Double.parseDouble()` code:

```
if (result.e < -1024) {
    result.zero = true;
    return result;
} else if (result.e > 1024) {
    result.infinity = true;
    return result;
}
```

Double has the exponencial view `MeP`, where `M - mantissa` and `P - exponent` (`MeP` is equal to `M*10^P`). Android firstly checks if exponent exists, and if it is `> 1024`, decides it is `Infinity` and stops any other verifications.

In this code we can see, that in case if after `e` letter is any negative number, less than `1024`, this number is recognized as correct but equal to `zero`.

```
Double.parseDouble("Any characterse1025"); //Infinity
Double.parseDouble("Any characterse-1025"); //0.0
```

And our case whit `UUID`s:

```
Double.parseDouble("4cff9d79-a696-4dfc-89f9-a265ae117257"); //Infinity
Double.parseDouble("4cff9d79-a696-4dfc-89fe-126534117257"); //0.0
```

So, it is not safe to use this method. Look for the alternatives.

**UPD:** [Original investigation page (ru)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/234193/). Translated not for a rate.

**UPD2:** Bug is [already fixed](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/102376/).