# Why does a very big double input return "Infinity" instead of error in Java?

Tags: java, double

Initializing a double variable with a value greater than `1E309` gives an error during compilation.
However, taking that value as an input does not produce any error. In fact, printing the double variable gives the `String` `"Infinity"`.
Why does this happen?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BigDouble {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double number;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a number:  ");
        number = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println(number);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what's your big double input? It might be `long`

Comment: I tried 1E6000 so that it would definitely be out of range

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442836/double-parsedouble-returns-infinity-when-i-thought-it-should-be-numberformatex

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Java's double gives infinity for anything from 1E309. But why doesn't it give an error as it would have had the variable been initialized with such a value?

Comment: @KBG literals were designed to have some bounds. If `1E6000` is out of the range, why should it be considered as a valid literal? Consider `double d = Double.parseDouble("1e6000");` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't get any errors because `nextDouble()` parses a `Double`, not a `double`. `Double` as a wrapper class, has several useful constants:

```
public static final double POSITIVE_INFINITY = 1.0 / 0.0;
public static final double NEGATIVE_INFINITY = -1.0 / 0.0;
public static final double NaN = 0.0d / 0.0;
```

Inside, `nextDouble()` uses `Double.parseDouble(String)` to provide a result regardless of the range the inputted number is in.

```
public double nextDouble() {
    ...
    try {
        return Double.parseDouble(processFloatToken(next(floatPattern())));
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        ...
    }
}
```

If the number is out of the `double` range, you will be given either `POSITIVE_INFINITY` or `NEGATIVE_INFINITY`.

```
"NaN" -> Double.parseDouble("NaN") -> Double.NaN -> NaN
"1E6000" -> Double.parseDouble("1E6000") -> Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY -> Infinity
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say, "Initializing a double variable with a value greater than `1E309`", you probably mean like:

```
double number = 1E6000;
```

Here, "1E6000" appearing as-is, is called a "literal" value. You are writing a program, and asking it that it literally uses this value as a double.

Which is impossible as this value is too large. So there is no sense allowing you to do that. Instead, use a value that can actually be represented, or if you want infinity, use constant Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY instead. Rejecting the literal 1E6000 is not taking away any options from you.

However, when you're not dealing with a literal value, but the result of some computing, then the common contract of floating-point numbers, is that if the value computed is too big to be represented, you provide infinity to represent it. Not an error.

Here the programmer has no way to predict that the user will type in a number too large to be represented exactly. There is no better alternative to propose, than to represent the value computed as a result, as infinity.